# How to get the path of picturebox image in resources and transfer it to a label

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that user register the required fields and they have an option to browse the image on their desktop. I'm not saving the actual image on my database. I used the Openfiledialog and when user select an image it will copy the path to a label, the selected image will be saved in my project folder and the path will be saved on my database. Now the problem is what if the user didn't want to have a picture?, to solve this problem i programmatically set an image to my picturebox using resources. Here's the problem now how can i get the image path of my picturebox (The image is in resources) and copy it to my label and also you can see that i have File.Copy function i don't want this code to be enabled when user doesn't select any image.

PS: Default Image like facebook if there's no Uploaded picture

```
public partial class RegisterCustomer : UserControl
{
    public RegisterCustomer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UserImage.Image = Properties.Resources.User;
        //var img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\dieth\source\repos\SalesInventoryManagement\SalesInventoryManagement\bin\Debug\Icons\User.png");
        //UserImage.Image = img;
    }     
    Register rc = new Register();
    private void Btn_Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.Copy(lbl_location.Text, Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\dieth\source\repos\SalesInventoryManagement\SalesInventoryManagement\bin\Picture", Path.GetFileName(lbl_location.Text)), true);
        rc.Insert(lbl_location.Text, string.Format(txt_firstname.Text + " " + txt_middlename.Text + " " + txt_lastname.Text), cbox_gender.Text, txt_contact.Text, txt_email.Text, txt_address.Text, Variables.Current_Date);
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Added", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    }
    private void Btn_Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rc.BrowseImage(UserImage, Variables.location , lbl_location);      
    }
}

public class Register
{
    public void Insert(string path, string Fullname, string Gender, string Contact_Number, string Email, string Home_Address, string Dates)
    {       
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SalesInventoryManagement.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertCustomer", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Images", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = path;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Full_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Fullname;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Gender;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Contact_Number", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11).Value = Contact_Number;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Email;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Home_Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Home_Address;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Dates", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Dates;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    public void BrowseImage(PictureBox UserImage, string location, Label path)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            ofd.Filter = "Image Files (*.jpg;*.jpeg;.*.png; | *.jpg;*.jpeg;.*.png;)";
            ofd.FilterIndex = 1;
            ofd.Multiselect = false;
            ofd.Title = "Select Image File";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                location = ofd.FileName;
                path.Text = location;
                UserImage.Image = Image.FromFile(location);
                UserImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;             
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the resource path using following.

```
var path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                                          @"..\..\Resources","User.png"));
```

Comment: var path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                                          @"C:\Users\dieth\source\repos\SalesInventoryManagement\SalesInventoryManagement\bin\Picture", "User.png"));

I modified your code , since i got this error "could not find this path"
this path in my code is where my User.png is

Comment: You are passing the complete path as second parameter. I don' think you would want to hard code the full path. You should probably use "Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,@"..\Picture"))"